# Generate a column in dataframe containing next business day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have two dataframes that look like this:

```
dict1 = {'lastDate': {0: Timestamp('2015-04-01 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2014-12-31 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2015-02-10 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2015-03-31 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2015-04-17 00:00:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2015-05-05 00:00:00'),
  6: Timestamp('2015-06-22 00:00:00'),
  7: Timestamp('2015-07-19 00:00:00'),
  8: Timestamp('2015-09-20 00:00:00'),
  9: Timestamp('2015-12-11 00:00:00')},
 'countryCode': {0: 'JPN',
  1: 'JPN',
  2: 'JPN',
  3: 'JPN',
  4: 'JPN',
  5: 'JPN',
  6: 'JPN',
  7: 'JPN',
  8: 'JPN',
  9: 'JPN'}}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict1)

dict2 = {'countryCode': {6617: 'JPN',
  6618: 'JPN',
  6619: 'JPN',
  6620: 'JPN',
  6621: 'JPN',
  6622: 'JPN',
  6623: 'JPN',
  6624: 'JPN',
  6625: 'JPN',
  6626: 'JPN'},
 'publicHoliday': {6617: '2015-01-01 00:00:00.000',
  6618: '2015-01-02 00:00:00.000',
  6619: '2015-01-12 00:00:00.000',
  6620: '2015-02-11 00:00:00.000',
  6621: '2015-04-29 00:00:00.000',
  6622: '2015-05-04 00:00:00.000',
  6623: '2015-05-05 00:00:00.000',
  6624: '2015-05-06 00:00:00.000',
  6625: '2015-07-20 00:00:00.000',
  6626: '2015-09-21 00:00:00.000'}}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict2)
```

`df1` contains a list of countries and dates and `df2` contains a list of all public holidays for all countries from `df1`.

I want to write a function that will create a new column in `df1` called `nextBusinessDay`, based on the value in `df1['lastDate']`.

For example, the first date in `df1` is `2014-12-31` which was on a Wednesday. As per `df2`, `2015-01-01` and `2015-01-02` were bank holidays and `2015-01-03` and `2015-01-04` were weekend days, so the next available date is `2015-01-05`.

This is the function I have so far, but it doesn’t incorporate the geographical component yet.

```
import holidays

oneDay = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
publicHolidays = df2['publicHoliday'].values.tolist()

def nbd():
    nextDay = x + oneDay
    while nextDay.weekday() in holidays.WEEKEND or nextDay in publicHolidays:
        next_day += oneDay
    return nextDay
```

Any ideas on how I can reflect the geographical component as well?

Comment: At a very basic level this would be easy to do. But wanting to incorporate bank holidays and geography it becomes much more complex of an issue.. I've never had to do something like this so I'm not sure what solutions are available but my first thought would be to look for an API to handle this for you

Comment: @rayad yeah, I tried multiple things but I couldn’t get it to work

Comment: You may need to do [`tz_localize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.tz_localize.html) like `df1['lastDate'].apply(lambda x: x.tz_localize(tz='Japan'))`  and also for `df2['publicHoliday']` before applying that function

Comment: A quick search for an api came up with the 'Working Days' api. Have a Google for APIs and I'm sure you'll find something that fits your needs